# UIWebView with authorisation, use same auth when clicking links

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I have a UIWebView that navigates to a webpage using Basic Authorisation using this code

```
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)];
    [urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Now when a link is clicked, the webView's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is fired but the page isn't loaded because the next page also needs the authorisation.

Is there a way to automatically add the Auth to the links clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just do the same thing to the request that you get in shouldStartLoadWithRequest: ?

Comment: I've tried creating a new request from there, but it ends up in a continuous loop

Comment: I first responded incorrectly.  See my updated answer to avoid a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to properly create a new request in shouldStartLoad

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    BOOL shouldNavigate = NO;
    NSString *existingAuthValue = [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    if (existingAuthValue == nil)
    {
        NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)];
        [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:request.URL];
        //Append any other info from the old request
        [webView performSelector:@selector(loadRequest:) withObject:newRequest afterDelay:0];
    }
    else
    {
        shouldNavigate = YES;
    }
    return shouldNavigate;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't taking into account that NSURLRequest != NSMutableURLRequest.  I'll update the code.

Comment: It doesn't work. Im assuming because it's not an NSMutableURLRequest? So I can't add to it.

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer, I dont have a loadRequest method so i'm getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: It's ok, i've got it working with your code now, Thanks. Just 1 more problem though, when I submit a form I end up with a blank screen. Is this because i'm changing the request?

Comment: Yes.  That falls under the umbrella of //Append any other info from the old request.  Change the request method (to POST most likely, but just use whatever the old request had), duplicate all the headers, and any content like the HTTPBody.  You could write a helper method that returns a mutable request from your original request and does this.  Also, the selector error was because I wrote self instead of webView, assuming that it was a UIWebView subclass being its own delegate...which I should not have assumed.  Its also better practice to use the object passed to the delegate in this case.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I added `[newRequest setHTTPBody:[request HTTPBody]];` `[newRequest setHTTPMethod:[request HTTPMethod]];` and it's working great now.